# tfs53010 error. TFS Build agent does nothing

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

just installed a fresh version of TFS 2015 on a box, everything is working fine and now i'm trying to get builds working, but I'm getting the below error repeating on me over and over.
I'm using the default local service auth for the build service, but i get the same error with a custom user as well.  The VSO agent is shown as running in services and the TFS admin console, but any time i start a queue it just sits there, waiting for the build service.
All the errors that i find online have stacktraces that seem much more informative than mine.  If you're interested [here](https://gist.github.com/vishnu4/d4ad7a829f077a8719bb) is a gist of the most recent log entry in D:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Build_diag .
Does anyone have any ideas?

```
    TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 12/3/2015 1:24:00 AM
Machine: 
Application Domain: TfsJobAgent.exe
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v4.0.30319
Service Host: 
Process Details:
  Process Name: TfsJobAgent
  Process Id: 1584
  Thread Id: 2216
  Account name: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE

Detailed Message: There was an error during job agent execution. The operation will be retried. Similar errors in the next five minutes may not be logged.
Exception Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (type TargetInvocationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance[T]()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ComponentCreator`1.Create(ISqlConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Int32 commandTimeout, Int32 deadlockPause, Int32 maxDeadlockRetries, ITFLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationResourceManagementService.CreateComponentRaw[TComponent](ISqlConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Int32 commandTimeout, Int32 deadlockPause, Int32 maxDeadlockRetries, Boolean handleNoResourceManagementSchema, Boolean verifyServiceVersion, Boolean throwExceptions, ITFLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.JobApplication.SetupInternal()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.JobServiceUtil.RetryOperationsUntilSuccessful(RetryOperations operations, Int32 maxTries, Int32& delayOnExceptionSeconds)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: External component has thrown an exception. (type SEHException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseManagementComponent15..ctor()
```

Comment: According to your log *MessageQueueListener.DispatchAsync* is  related to Microsoft Team Foundation Server Message Queue Application Pool  , try to stop and restart it.

Comment: I've restarted every service related to TFS, and restarted the server.  No change